# Android RequestMultiplePermissions(): one of the permission's status is never true, even after allowing it

Tags: java, android, runtime-permissions

I want to ask for the `SEND_SMS` and `READ_SMS` runtime permissions, if they are not given. This is my code:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> mRequestPermissionsLauncher;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mRequestPermissionsLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
         Log.d("DEBUG",result.toString());
    });

    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
         if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) || shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)){
              new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                   .setTitle("Permission Needed")
                   .setMessage("Please press OK to allow the permissions")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("OK", (dialog, which) -> mRequestPermissionsLauncher.launch(PERMISSIONS)).create().show();
         }
         else{
             mRequestPermissionsLauncher.launch(PERMISSIONS);
         }
    }
}
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
         }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

After I allow the permissions and debug the `result`, it keeps showing:

```
{android.permission.SEND_SMS=true, android.permission.READ_SMS=false}
```

Why is my `READ_SMS` permission false?

**EDIT:** Never mind, the issue is resolved. I forgot to declare the `READ_SMS` permission in the manifest file. Silly me :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and that's by design - to prevent abuse.

You're better of following the [official guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#workflow_for_requesting_permissions).

The only way to request permissions again, is to navigate the user to app info, where the user has to manually allow it:

```kotlin
fun launchPermissionSettings(context: Context) {
    Intent().apply {
        action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
        data = Uri.fromParts("package", context.packageName, null)

        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)

        context.startActivity(this)
    }
}
```

```java
static void launchPermissionSettings(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("package", context.getPackageName(), null));

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);

    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

You're also using a deprecated way of requesting permissions. Consider using `ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()`:

```kotlin
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mRequestPermissionsLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Array<String>>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mRequestPermissionsLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { result: Map<String, Boolean> ->
            //Handle result here
        }

        //Request permissions like this:
        mRequestPermissionsLauncher.launch(arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
        ))
    }
}
```

```java
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> mRequestPermissionsLauncher;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mRequestPermissionsLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), result -> {
            //Handle activity result here
        });

        //Request permissions like this:
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS,
            Manifest.permission.READ_SMS,
        };
        mRequestPermissionsLauncher.launch(PERMISSIONS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the `java` version (in which the post was intended), as I am not adept in Kotlin?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute